# Partitioning in ubuntu as only os

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ntfs, ext4

I am a total newbie. just installed Ubuntu and erased my windows  , so i have Ubuntu as my main now, i have 2 questions:

1. After finishing installation, there is a 512 mb partition. 8 GB swap, and 900 GB ext4, what to do to after that to partition my disk and what extension to give to use as a normal volume as in Windows?
2. When i try to make new volume in NTFS (it have to be NTFS right?) I give the partition a name but it don't appear as a name when i run ubuntu. When the mouse is over it it just says for ex : 500 gb and the name is in number and letters.

Comment: http://www.tecmint.com/ubuntu-16-04-installation-guide/

this will help you out

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need 3 partitions. 2 ext4 and 1 swap. One 30 GB ext4 is enough for  Ubuntu system files termed as / (root partition). One swap can be as big or twice as big as your physical RAM. Another ext4 can be the rest of the disk as /home. This is where your personal files are to be stored. So, ideally the partition table will be / , /home, swap. Remember to install grub on the MBR, not on partitions. Your partitions will look like sda1, sda2, sda3. Grub will be in sda (no numericals).

Comment: I dont know anything about MBR tbh , the lartitions was made automatically, as follows: 512 mb fat32 for efi system partition, linux swap 7.95 (i got 8 gb rams), and the the rest of my whole hard disk in a ext4 extension and 80 gb is being used from it , i think the grub is installed there, can i take all the other space other than the 80 gb used and make 2 other partitions for me?

Comment: It's because that largest partition includes both / & /home. You don't need more partition.

Comment: Yes but they dont appear on normal ubuntu  i need to partition a value from it and make it ntfs

Comment: But why do you need ntfs?

Comment: i dont know the difference between ntfs and ext4 , but the ext4 partition dont appear in my disks , when i make a partition in ntfs it appears :/